# Changing the site name?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

The proposal name passed through the commit stage as **Veganism & Vegetarianism**, but it seems to have been renamed to just **Vegetarianism** - I don't feel this properly reflects the aims of the site as the two are quite different things.

Would it be possible to rename the site? If the former title was too long then maybe something that reflects both subjects in a shorter form?

Comment: Suggestion for a shorter name to cover your request?

Comment: @Steve `veg*n` is a common term for both groups, but I'm not sure it would be a popular SE name due to the asterisk

Comment: Despite the asterisk, I am not sure it is a good name, especially in the early days..  If you don't know what it means you don't know, and we need to attract users.   Having said that, Stack Overflow?  But that site now has critical mass.

Comment: The main reason *was* the length of the title was a bit of a mouthful, but we're listening. As **[mentioned below](http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/8/34)**, it is often untenable to list every interest directly in the title of the site, but I'd like to hear the pros and cons as answers below.  We will consider the issue of **concise labels versus community identity** before the site gets too far along.

Comment: Veganism can be seen as a stricter subset of vegetarianism, for those who consider dairy products as unhealthy or for those countries where healthy dairy products are not available.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's two issues here IMO, the site name and the URL.

I agree with those who oppose using "vegetarianism" alone. It can be confusing when coming on the site with a vegan interest. It is not obvious to everyone that both fields are covered: "vegetarianism" is not a perfect superset of "veganism".The term "vegetarianism" is generally understood as focusing on a meat-free *diet* while "veganism" goes far beyond food, including everyday things like shoes or even [money](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/nov/29/bank-of-england-urged-to-make-new-5-note-vegan-friendly).

I personally don't mind a super long site name: in everyday use, it will find an accepted abbreviation right away. Software Engineering, English Language Learners, or Theoretical Physics aren't super catchy names either.

I'd vote for making the site name

> **Veganism & Vegetarianism**

as intended. (Or the other way 'round, whatever.)

"V&V" would become the accepted abbreviation in a heartbeat.

The URL is a different thing: even just "vegetarianism" makes for an awfully long URL with the ".stackexchange.com" domain name. Remember, this is going to be the site's URL *forever*.

I'd suggest an abbreviation that should be acceptable to both vegans and vegetarians, is short, and fairly unambiguous:

> **veg.stackexchange.com**

Comment: `veg.stackexchange.com` Just great!

Comment: +1 for veg.stackexchange.com. Regarding V&V, there's already Vi&Vim, so maybe confusion would arise there!

Comment: This seems to be consensus. How do we now technically bring this change about?

Comment: @Turion I guess we'll have to wait for the community team to review this and make a decision (if they feel it's already time). I'll ping Robert in a couple days if there's nothing else happening

Comment: I guess the general topic differs enough to be easily distinguished from context. So no worries about Vi&Vim.

Comment: Also, vim.se is often referred to just as vim.se, so it might not be too big of a deal.

Answer (score 4):

Vegetarianism can be interpreted in the strict "vegetarian diet" sense, but it can also be interpreted in the broader sense of "diets that focus on abstaining from the consumption of animal products".

The site title uses the broader interpretation.

I'm not going to argue which interpretation is the "correct" or "best" one, as that doesn't really matter, the important question here is:

> Is the site's on-topic content clear from the title? Would any prospective member be confused about it?

And I think it is. I strongly doubt that a vegan prospective member would find the site's intentions unclear from the title "vegetarianism".

---

- *Veganism & Vegetarianism* is pretty long, and I don't think it clarifies things. Besides, to be *really* complete it would also have to include a long list of other terms.
- I have never heard of "veg*n". I find this a confusing title.

Comment: @lifetimes Sure, veganism is a lot of more involved, but in general understanding "vegetarianism" is interpreted as a catch-all term by many people (including, for example, the Wikipedia page and the Vegetarian society). As for "Vegans would be put off", meh :-/ I wish people would be more practical about these sort of semantics, but that *might* be a good reason to change it to the longer title anyway. The question is: are these a few individuals, or is this a wide-shared belief?

Comment: I joined the site and it was not at all clear to me that vegan questions would be on topic because the title said only "vegetarianism". It's not a good 100% catch-all IMO. Not because someone might feel put off, I really don't care about that, but because new members might very well feel discouraged from asking about that specific topic, or take away the impression that it's only about meat-free diets and nothing else.